# django attributeerror type object 'Payment' has no attribute _meta

Tags: python, django, attributeerror, create-view

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to create my first simple app.

I want to try out the createView, but I keep getting an error when trying to call the corresponding template.

Here's the error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.2.55:8000/colist/paymentNew/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'polls',
 'colist')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  201.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get
  159.         form_class = self.get_form_class()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_form_class
  118.             return model_forms.modelform_factory(model, fields=self.fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in modelform_factory
  528.     return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __new__
  282.                                       opts.help_texts, opts.error_messages)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in fields_for_model
  175.     opts = model._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /colist/paymentNew/
Exception Value: type object 'Payment' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class User(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics/', default='pics/test.jpg')
    email = models.EmailField()
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName

class Bill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    newBalance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date = models.DateTimeField('payment date')
```

Snippet from views.py

```
[...other stuff...]

class Payment(ListView):
    model = Payment
    template_name = 'colist/payment.html' 

class PaymentNew(CreateView):
    model = Payment
    template_name = 'colist/paymentNew.html' 

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('colist:paymentNew')
```

and the template paymentNew.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<body>

<h1>Payments</h1>

<ul>
    {% for payment in object_list %}
        <li class="payment">
            {{ payment.user.firstName }}  {{payment.user.lastName}}   {{payment.amount}} EUR   {{payment.date}}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


<form action="{% url 'colist:paymentNew' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        {{ form.as_ul }}
    </ul>
    <input id="save_payment" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<a href= "{% url "colist:payment" %}"> back to list </a>

</body>
```

I don't know where the "_meta" attribute should come from.
Also I noticed, when playing around with this error: If I change the model in views.py for the model "Bill" instead of "Payment" like so:

```
class PaymentNew(CreateView):
    model = Bill
    template_name = 'colist/paymentNew.html' 

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('colist:paymentNew')
```

Why is it working with Bill instead of Payment? I don't see any big difference between the two.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have another class in your view called Payment?

Comment: Yes I do. I edited the views.py. If I delete this payment class, the error changes to "type object 'Payment' has no attribute 'as_view'". But this might be related to the urls.py... give me a second

Comment: Ok. That's it. My urls.py looked like this:

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^(?P<last_order_id>\d+)$', views.index, name='index'),
     url(r'^order/$', views.order, name='order'),
     url(r'^payment/$', views.Payment.as_view(),name='payment'),
     url(r'^paymentNew/$', views.PaymentNew.as_view(), name='paymentNew'),
    )

The url ".../paymentNew.html" matched for this line

    url(r'^payment/$', ...

instead of 

    url(r'^paymentNew/$', ...

I can not answer my own question...hence, as comment

Comment: sure you can answer your own question. it's encouraged, in fact :^)

note that you do have to wait to *accept* your own answer, two days as I recall.